# xcappdata contains only AppData folder after download from Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I have upgraded my XCode to version 4.4 recently and I realized that when I download the sandbox contains of my app from the organizer, it only contains AppData folder and AppDataInfo.plist. The Documents folder is missing, although I can see it in the Organizer's Sandbox listing.

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading to xcode 4.4.  Have you found anything to solve it?

Comment: no, i still not getting all the folders.

Answer (score 2):

This was reported as a bug and will be fixed as part of version 4.4.1.

Update**
xcode 4.4.1 which fixes this, was released on August 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Xcode 4.4 on 10.7 and 10.8, seems that the only option
is to keep using 4.3 series for now.

Unfortunately I had good reasons to update my dev machines to Mountain Lion asap and
it requires Xcode 4.4 to begin with. Starting Xcode 4.3 on Mountain Lion gives an
error dialog, urging to upgrade to 4.4 or later.

If you're on ML, try running the following command as a temporary fix before starting 4.3:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTSkipAllowedVersionsCheck -bool YES
```

and revert it later on with

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTSkipAllowedVersionsCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Xcode 4.4.1. Works fine now.